# Trouble with Fetch from JS to Django view

Tags: javascript, django

I could use assistance understanding and fixing my error for the following:

Javascript calls the following function during some event on the page:

```
function load_homePage() {
    
    // Pull all posts
    fetch('/homepage')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
      
      // Print all posts
      posts.forEach( function(post) {
          console.log(post)
        })
    })
}
```

Eventually, I will have JS create dynamic Div's to display all the data that comes in from the call.

Fetch is calling to the following view:

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def view_homePage(request):
    
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    
    # Return entire set of posts to webpage
    return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts],   
      safe=False)
```

Here all I want is for Django to query the database, pull all the data from the Post model, and send it back to the page. The model is as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

    class User(AbstractUser):
        pass

    class Post(models.Model):
        posterID = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE,  
           related_name="post")
        content = models.TextField(blank=False)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def serialize(self):
            return {
                "id": self.id,
                "posterID": self.posterID,
                "content": self.content,
                "timestamp": self.timestamp
            }
```

The Url.py file is also complete:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path("", views.index, name="index"),
     path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
     path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
     path("register", views.register, name="register"),
     path("post", views.new_post, name="posts"),
     path("homepage", views.view_homePage, name="homepage")
]
```

When I try to get the event to fire I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable
[23/Sep/2020 02:51:09] "GET /homepage HTTP/1.1" 500 107660
```

Can someone advise me as to what I am doing incorrectly and how to do it correctly? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer and thought I would post it here in case it is of value to anyone. The issue is in the model code. Specifically here:

```
def serialize(self):
    return {
       "id": self.id,
  --->"posterID": self.posterID,<----
       "content": self.content,
       "timestamp": self.timestamp
    }
```

Being a foreign key to User, it was returning:
"posterID": User: someName

I fixed it by changing the offending line to:

```
"posterID": self.posterID.id,
```